# Customize ion select on Ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

At this moment ion combox is in front of ion label in the middle.

[image]

I want to put text on top and combobox selection below:

[image]

Is this possible on ionic 2?

EDIT:

HTML code follows Ionic API Documentation:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Align on Top</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="align">
    <ion-option value="t">top</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="m">middle</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this in .SCSS page and adjust values as needed

```
.select-md .select-icon,.select-ios.select-icon {
    position: absolute;
    width: 12px;
    height: 19px;
    left: 15px;
    top: 26px;
}
```

and change the label to stacked

```
<ion-label stacked>Align on Top</ion-label>
```

Comment: Your answer is correct for select but how can I move label "Allign..." to top?

Comment: dont know this will solve ur issue, but u can try this

Comment: I will accept your answer but in the second case I resolve it by:                 ion-label {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
    align-self: flex-start;
}

Comment: ok sure, but this is not a common issue, you just want to customize th ui as per ur need, i just showed you the idea, Thank u..